# Finding documents with $in, using an array of another document

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to built a friendship system with Meteor.js, Blaze and Mongodb. I'm at the point where I want to display the friends of a user on his profile page.

I have the collection "users" that has the field "friends" which is the array the names of other uses can be pushed in or pulled out.

Simplified example of a user document:

```
"name" : "bob"
"friends" : ["value of name-field of user-document1", "value of name-field of user-document2", "etc."]
```

I tried to put this friends array inside a hidden input on the profile and use it from there to create a iteration on the profile-template.helpers:

```
<input id="friends" type="hidden" value="{{user.friends}}">
```

```
  friends() {
      var friends = document.getElementById("friends").value;
      var friendsArray = friends.split(",");
      return Users.find({name:{$in: friendsArray},})
     },
```

But thats not how it works. How can I use/get this field, that contains the friends-array for this $in operation to get the other users that are friends with bob? I also tried `this.friends` But that only seems to work for iterations.

I could use

```
{{#each friend in user.friends}}
{{friend}}
{{/each}}
```

to get the names of the friends at least but I wanted to include the little avatar of those friends on the display-friends section as well, so that wouldn't do.

Edit: The user variable is defined in the Template.user.helpers as:

```
  user: ()=> { 
    var user = FlowRouter.getParam('user');
    return Users.findOne({name: user});
  },
```

I tried to use `this.data.char.friends` inside the friends-function like so

```
  friends() {
   return Users.find({
   name: { $in: (this.data.user.friends) }
    });
},
```

But it gave me an console.log error:

```
Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: user is not defined
```

Comment: Inside your Blaze template you are using `<input id="friends" type="hidden" value="{{user.friends}}">` - how is the `user` variable defined? In your template helper `friends` you would ideally want to do something like `this.data.user.friends` (=get the value from the template data context) instead of getting that value from a rendered input field.

Comment: If I have both variables (friends() and user:) inside the same template.user.helpers could I still use "this.data.user.friends?" I tried to put it in like that but it gave me en error ^

Comment: @TKur : Ok basically you want to get details of each person listed in friends array based on a given user from mongoDB ? Does persons listed in friends Array of a user has their own records/data/documents in the same collection with unique id such as name/something ??

Comment: Yes, thats what I want. Every person listed in the friends array itself has his own document inside the user-collection. They also have they own ids of course. But the thing that gets saved inside friendarray is the name-field of that user-document.

Comment: @TKur : I've given my query try that and make sure you extract data from friendsDetails Array for friends details as individual objects !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this aggregation query, rather than doing multiple calls to DB for fetching required data :

```
db.getCollection('Users').aggregate([{ $match: { name: 'bob' } },
{
    $graphLookup: {
        from: "Users",
        startWith: "$friends",
        connectFromField: "friends",
        connectToField: "name",
        as: "friendsDetails"
    }
}, { $project: { name: 1, friends: 1, friendsDetails: { $filter: { input: '$friendsDetails', as: 'item', cond: { $ne: ['$$item.name', 'bob'] } } } } }])
```

Reason why we've `$project` and `$filter` is by default `$graphLookup` will return the requested User as well in list of `friendsDetails`, used these to remove it from end result.

Answer (score 0):

Ah no, it was actually more simple than that.

```
  friends() {
    var name = FlowRouter.getParam('user');
    return Users.find( { friends: { $in: [name] } } );
},
```

This one displays the friends on the profile just like that. I just have to figure out why it does that ...

Comment: Yes it is simple & nice, but don't you need the actual user's(bob) document to be returned in any case of your flow (in that case add, name : 'bob' to query)? and also your initial question was different to get the list of friends and store it somewhere then to retrieve the friends details. Also find query like that technically scans every document for a given name to be in friends list unless properly indexed vs $graphLookup needs only name to be indexed and gets the exact matches out quickly. So outcome is friends as an array (Vs) name as a string to be indexed, just check(n-1 vs 1-1)

Comment: The question didn't change though. What I tried to achieve was indeed retrieving the documents of those users saved inside that friends-array. And this way works for me. I tried your suggestion before but it didn't work out for me. It already failed on the getCollection - in Meteor some syntax details seem to be different on some areas. However, the bob-document would be already returned since it's on the profile where the displaying of the friends is happening. I'm eager to learn more methods of mongodb beyond the simple stuff but for now I'm happy with this result, thank you.

Comment: Ok good, regd. 'It already failed on the getCollection' - that's a db syntax you wouldn't be using that in code i.e; it doesn't matter whether it is meteor or any another when you've already defined a model you would go with that 'User.aggregate'. I must've anticipated that I need to give exact code(what I've given is a aggregation query to get results), alright when it's working as is cool, happy coding.